# Error with PHPUnit in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a error with PHPUnit using Symfony2

In my test case I import:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
```

But, when I execute it I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in C:\trabajo\web\Company\src\Company\WebBundle\Tests\dbTest.php on line 11
```

I use to execute it:

> phpunit -c app/ src/Company/WebBundle/Tests/dbTest

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you extend the class? `class dbTest extends WebTestCase`

Comment: Looks like a problem with your autoloader

Comment: Try to run just `phpunit -c app`

Answer (score 2):

This is because to execute the test case with CLI you need to provide

- boostrap file `/app/bootstrap.php.cache`
- configuration file `app/phpunit.xml.dist`

So the command would be like below:

```
phpunit --configuration app/phpunit.xml.dist ----bootstrap /app/bootstrap.php.cache
```

Bootstrap can be provided in phpunit.xml.dist as well within `<phpunit>` tag.

The other option assuming you have good phpunit.xml.dist file is to go to app directory and there execute the tests.

You may adjust the paths to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you extends the dbTest class:

```
<?php

namespace Company\WebBundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class dbTest extends WebTestCase
{
    ...
}
```